# translate regex to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I'm struggling with porting this function to PHP.

```
SomeString.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
```

To be honest I don't even know what exactly it does. 
I tried using at least the expression with `preg_replace`
but got

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 25

when using something like

```
preg_match('/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\\[\\]\\/\\])/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javascript function `.replace` is translated in php by `preg_replace`, so:

```
SomeString.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
```

becomes:

```
$SomeString = preg_replace('~([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]/\\\\])~', "\\\\$1", $SomeString);
```

This will replace the special characters in the character class by itself but escaped.

Apart of this, the error you've encountered is due to the double escape of the character in your attempt with preg_match, you have to double-double escape.

```
preg_match('/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\\\])/', $string, $matches);
//                           |     ^^^^^ double-double escape the backslash
//                           ^ no needs to double escape here
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
preg_match('#([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]/\\\\])#', $string, $matches);
```

Your error was use of `\\` instead of `\\\\` in your regex. Matching a backslash requires double escaping. One `\\` for PHP and another `\\` for PCRE engine.